# How to get the day of the week from a Unix timestamp (PHP)?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, weekday

How do I get the day (1-7) from a Unix timestamp in PHP? I also need the day date (1-31) and month (1-12).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$weekday = date('N', $timestamp); // 1-7
$month = date('m', $timestamp); // 1-12
$day = date('d', $timestamp); // 1-31
```

Comment: This undoubtedly works. But date() has to calculate the actual date three times just to pick one element each time. If you need all three values anyway, isn't that a bit suboptimal?

Comment: you can always use date('N.m.d etc.') at the same time for your purposes, i just gave the examples seperately to answer the question.

Comment: The formats 'm' and 'd' return single digit numbers with leading zeros. It looks like the OP requested numbers without leading zeros ('j' and 'n' from @Dyllon's answer).

Answer (score 10):

see http://docs.php.net/getdate

e.g.

```
$ts = time(); // could be any timestamp
$d=getdate($ts);

echo 'day of the week: ', $d['wday'], "\n";
echo 'day of the month: ', $d['mday'], "\n";
echo 'month: ', $d['mon'], "\n";
```

Comment: 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

Comment: Thanks @PedroLobito for the precision. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

It's the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function you're after.

You can get more details from the PHP manual but in a nutshell here are the functions you need.

```
date('N', $timestamp);
//numeric representation of the day of the week

date('j', $timestamp);
//Day of the month without leading zeros

date('n', $timestamp);
//Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [date](http://php.net/date) function as stated before, with your `$timestamp` as the second argument:

```
$weekday = date('N', $timestamp); // 1 = Monday to 7 = Sunday
$month = date('m', $timestamp); // 1-12 = Jan-Dec
$day = date('d', $timestamp); // 1-31, day of the month
```

Not all PHP versions play nice with negative timestamps. My experience is that timestamps dating back to before the UNIX epoch fare better with the new [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

Answer (score 2):

```
print "Week".date('N')."\n";
print "day of month " .date('d')."\n";
print "month ".date('m')."\n";
```