# Getting day of week from timestamp PHP

Tags: php, date

i am trying to get the day of week from a timestamp:

an example of the timestamp could be:

```
2014-09-14 18:28:11
```

I have tried with the following code:

```
$date = date("D", strtotime($activity[$i]['timestamp']));
```

However the result i get here is:

```
Thu
```

which should have been sunday?

Also is it possible to get it as a full discription instead of a short version of the day name?

Comment: Not reproducible, it does output `Sun` here: http://3v4l.org/gBKLE

Comment: @CBroe i kid you not it returns thursday at my place

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475550/getting-the-day-from-a-unix-timestamp-php

Comment: The value you are working with is clearly not what you think it is. You need to figure out why.

Comment: Check if your system clock has the correct date and time set.

Comment: LoL yeah i forgot its inside a for loop so  i had to put [$i] infront of ['timestamp'] updating my question

Comment: Is it inside a loop , looks like that.

Comment: It looks like the {strtotime()} function has been ignored by the code. So the day is not probably formatted So take look at your code, what this part does { $activity[$i]['timestamp'] }

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: PHP's [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) can do a great job to simplify code. Just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to part two of the question is that you can just use [l (lowercase 'L')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and it'll output Sunday instead of Sun.

```
$date = date("l", strtotime($activity[$i]['timestamp']));
```

As for the first part, it probably output `Thursday, 1 January 1970` because it received an error instead of an actual date as argument to `strtotime`.