# JSon Date Parsing from weather api

Tags: android, json

i have been parsing data from my weather i am successfully able to extract description,min and max temperature but date is in unknown format how to process the date to convert it into readable format

```
  "list":[  
  {  
     "dt":1497852000,
     "temp":{  
        "day":301.14,
        "min":294.81,
        "max":301.14,
        "night":294.81,
        "eve":301.14,
        "morn":301.14
     },
"pressure":990.68,
     "humidity":88,
     "weather":[  
        {  
           "id":501,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"moderate rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
```

My Code:

```
 public static void JSONParsing(String forecastJsonStr) throws JSONException {
    double MinTemp;
    double MaxTemp;
    String Date,description;
    JSONObject forecastDate = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
    JSONArray ForecastData = forecastDate.getJSONArray("list");
    for(int i =0 ; i< ForecastData.length();i++){
        JSONObject weather = ForecastData.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject Data = weather.getJSONObject("temp");
        JSONObject Description = weather.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
         description = Description.getString("description");
        MinTemp = Data.getDouble("min");
        MaxTemp = Data.getDouble("max");


    }
}
```

Comment: What format is it actually in within the JSON?

Comment: your date is represented by `dt` , you can integrate the solution into your code

Answer (score 1):

Your date is in `seconds` as `long` type so fetch the `dt` as long then multiply it with `1000` to convert it into `miliseconds` the use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`

1.) Fetch your Date as `long`

2.) Pass it to `Date` class constructor while multiplying it with `1000` to converts seconds into milisecond

3.) Create and apply `SimpleDateFormat` to get your date

e.g

```
    String s1 ="{\"dt\":1497852000}";
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(s1);

    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(jsonObject2.getLong("dt")*1000);
    SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    String dateText = date_format.format(date);
    System.out.println(dateText);
```

Output :

```
19/06/17
```

Note : Since your `JSONResponse` in incomplete so i just added a simple case demonstrating your issue

Comment: I too am stuck with this problem from numerous weather API's who return the date as Epoch time. What I want to be able to do is simply convert that string to a day name like "Monday", "Tuesday" etc is there an easy function in php to do this with the parsed JSON data?

Comment: @MitchellK you can use [`getdate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2475555/4936904) and use `$d['weekday']` to get the day, here the complete detail http://docs.php.net/getdate

Comment: Thanks @Pavneet_Singh I also found another nice way of formatting the date for my output if it helps anyone else in future. 
For the day name `$day1 = date('l', $jsondata['daily']['data'][0]['time']);` and for a nicely formatted date `$day1d = date('  (d-M-Y)', $jsondata['daily']['data'][0]['time']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can format like this,

```
    try {
        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);


        JSONArray listJsonArray = responseObject.optJSONArray("list");

        if (listJsonArray == null || listJsonArray.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject eachDayJson = listJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

            if (eachDayJson == null) {
                continue;
            }

            long dateInSeconds = eachDayJson.optLong("dt"); // Get date as seconds

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");

            String readableDate = format.format(new Date(dateInSeconds * 1000)); // convert that in milliseconds

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```